# Uncaught Error: Module name "util" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am using a third party js file to format json. The js file is in the following format.

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util'),
    EE = require('events').EventEmitter;


module.exports = JSONTreeView;
util.inherits(JSONTreeView, EE);


function JSONTreeView(name_, value_, parent_, isRoot_){
    var self = this;

    if (typeof isRoot_ === 'undefined' && arguments.length < 4) {
        isRoot_ = true;
    }

    EE.call(self);

    if(arguments.length < 2){
        value_ = name_;
        name_ = undefined;
    } 
 }
```

This is in node.js format. But my project is of ojet using require js.

When I load the file in my html, I am getting error
Uncaught Error: Module name "util" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]).

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS uses different modules format - CommonJS. These formats are not compatible. You have to either convert it or instruct the ReqireJS on how to load them. All the information is available in the [RequireJS documentation](https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html)